# form to email PHP script

Tags: php, forms, server-side

I have this simple script I found online but it does not work. What am I missing?

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$email_from = $visitor_email;
$email_subject = "New Message";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from $name.\n".
    "\n\n $message".

$to = "myemail@domain.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

try{
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //done. redirect to thank-you page.
    header('Location: thank-you.html');
} catch(Exception $e){
    //problem, redirect to sorry page
    header('Location: sorry.html');
}       
?>
```

I am always redirected to the thank-you page but I do not get any emails.
All HTML stuff are correct.

Comment: You still can access the file directly, only thing you do is `echo` an error but the rest will be processed. Do a `die('msg');` to make sure the script can not be accessed. And do the `if` as `if (!$_POST)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a form similar to the following with named fields: (input fields must be named).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="handler.php">

Name: 
<input type="text" name="name" /> <br/>

Your Email: 
<input type="text" name="email" /> <br/>

Message: <br>
<textarea id="body" name="message" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Email" />

</body>
</html>
```

This line would cause you problems because of the dot at the end of `$message`.

```
$email_body = "You have received a new message from $name.\n".
"\n\n $message".
```

The dot should be a semi-colon `;` such as:

```
$email_body = "You have received a new message from $name.\n".
"\n\n $message";
```

In testing, the message I typed did not come through until changed to a semi-colon.

This line `echo "error; you need to submit the form!";` should be a `die()` directive in order to stop executing.

Such as: `die("Error. You need to submit the form.");` or you could use `exit;` under your `echo` also.

Such as:

```
echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
exit;
```

### PHP (handler.php)

Tested and working on my end using the form shown above.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
// echo "Error. You need to submit the form.";
// exit;
    die("Error. You need to submit the form.");
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$email_from = $visitor_email;
$email_subject = "New Message";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from $name.\n".
    "\n\n $message";

$to = "myemail@domain.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

try{
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //done. redirect to thank-you page.
// header('Location: thank-you.html');

echo "Success"; // My echo test

} catch(Exception $e){
    //problem, redirect to sorry page
// header('Location: sorry.html');

echo "Sorry"; // My echo test
}       
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm surprised there was no compilation errors with the dot instead of the semicolon. I'm marking this as accepted but in my case I think the (free) host I'm using does not support using sendmail from PHP so it still does not work for me.

Comment: @MinaHany You're very much welcome. There was a similar problem with another person about 2 weeks ago where their Free hosting did not provide `mail()`.

Comment: @MinaHany I suggest you look into http://www.000webhost.com/ they provide `mail` and I use it for testing purposes. They are free and also have MySQLi / PDO available, which is another reason I use them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the localhost, you cannot send an email. Only when your code is online the information will be sent.

You can try an easier method called the PHPmailer.
Here is an example,

```
  require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
```

echo "Message sent!";
}

Php mailer made it easier for the coder by calling methods and properties, also embedding images to a mail is so easy.

Still if you are on local host you cannot send an email.

Comment: Yes I do realise that and I'm not on localhost.

Comment: Pray tell, how is this PHPMailer going to send mail when `mail()` won't?

Comment: It is just an alternative, worth trying!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your spam filter in your e-mail?

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: The e-mail service provider on the receiving end might block it if you are not using a well-known e-mail service to send it (sorry, I dont know the right terms for it). I had this problem once. It didn't work to send the mail to some government account, but sending it to G-mail worked.

Comment: I am sending to gmail and I'm entering a gmail address as the sender as well.

Comment: @MinaHany: I wonder if gmail is dumb enough to say "From whoever@gmail.com?  Must be legit!  Never mind it didn't originate with our servers..."